# Partition Removal Failure. Memory is now missing

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I was trying to get rid of an old Bootcamp partition I didn't want on my 2012 Mac Mini. I was removing it from the disk utility app and I lost power half way through. Now the partition is gone, but the space it used to occupy hasn't been merged back to the main disk partition it's just gone. My SSD is 1 TB, but is only 775 GB, the same as it used to be.

What happened to this extra space and how can I get it back?

Comment: The solution may be as simple as reformatting the deleted partition as an APFS volume. Before making any changes, let’s understand the current state of your drive. Please share the output of diskutil list; diskutil apfs list

Answer (score 0):

This definitley sounds like your partition wasn't completely removed. Please note that the best way to get rid of a BootCamp Partition is to go to BootCamp Assistant and remove it.

The first step you should try is opening BootCamp Assistant and then checking if you can merge the partitions so that all the data on Windows is destroyed and the space used is merged with the macOS partition.

If that doesn't work, go to Disk Utility and run First Aid on the SSD (APPLE SSD SM0120G Media or whatever your SSD is called). Then, click on your APFS container and extend the disk space available for it. Then you might also need to make sure that Macintosh HD occupies all of the Container Disk.

If that doesn't work, you can try running First Aid in Safe Mode and macOS Recovery.

If you prefer, you can use `diskutil repairDisk` in Terminal with or instead of First Aid.

Link for using Safe Mode:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Link for using macOS Recovery:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314